# Manual button click works, but not Form1_Load

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2010

If I click on the button manually it works fine. If I try to load it through `Form1_Load`, everything works but one line.

Code:

```
public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            playTrend_Click(sender, e);
        }

private void playTrend_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            aaTrendControl1.FileOpenEx("\\\\path\\tochart\\e_chart.aaTrend");
            aaTrendControl1.ToolBarVisible = true;
            aaTrendControl1.TimeBarVisible = false;                  
            aaTrendControl1.TagPickerVisible = false; 
            aaTrendControl1.RealTimeMode = true;
            aaTrendControl1.GridVisible = false;
        }
private void aaTrendControl1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
```

If I click on the `playTrend` button manually, everything works just fine. However when running through the `Form1_Load` procedure, everything executes as it should, except for `aaTrendControl1.GridVisible = false;`

Any ideas?

Comment: Can you create a `Form_Shown` event handler, move the `playTrend_Click(sender, e)` line there? See if that works. One wild thought is that the chart might be displaying itself.

Comment: I saw that elsewhere when I looked for a solution, but no luck with that either. It does the same thing.

Comment: I would have said form shown as well. Usually this is as the form hasn't been shown yet, it's not visible so setting the visibility of a control on it has no effect.

Comment: so when you step that lien in  the debugger, does the property actually change. PS add a method called PlayTrend, and call it from the button and anywhere else you want to do it. What you've done calling the event handler is a terrible practice.

Comment: Well, originally when I tried switching from load to shown, I only changed in the code. This time I changed it via the designer view and the lightning bolt - doing it that way worked. Thanks for your help Jesse.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `Shown` event instead of `Load`.. The Load event is raised before the form is displayed for the first time and the Shown event is raised after the form is displayed for the first time. Hence your `aaTrendControl1` is not displayed and you cannot hide/show it in the Load event

Comment: You said `you cannot hide/show it in the Load event` - unless this is *specific* to the TrendControl in question, that statement does not hold true. You *can* show and hide controls on `Form_Load`.

Comment: @Jesse apparently not his trendcontrol